# For which x does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}(x+3)^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I determine for which $x$ the following series converges

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n}(x+3)^n$$

I suspect I might have to use the comparison test here but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the ratio  test we have, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}(x+3)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}(x+3)^{n}}=\sqrt{1+\frac1n}\cdot(x+3) \to x+3
$$ then we get a convergence for $|x+3|<1$.

Comment: (after dealing separately with the cases where the ratio test is uninformative)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, the seperate cases are obvious: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

Application of the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) reveals

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\sqrt{n}(x+3)^n\right|^{1/n}=|x+3|}$$

Note that in arriving at this result, we used $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}=1$.

> **The series converges, therefore, when $|x+3|<1$, and diverges for $|x+3|>1$.**

When $|x+3|=1$ the terms of the series do not approach zero and the series diverges.